XGBoost with time lagged predictors
I have a prediction problem that involves an outcome $Y_t$ and predictors $X_t$ that vary with time $t$. I want to fit a regression of $Y_t$ on $(t,X_t)$ including also lagged versions of $X$, i.e., $X_{t-1}$, $X_{t-2}$, etc. I am working with a large dataset and for memory efficiency do not want to make actual lagged copies of $X_t$ in the design matrix. Is there any way to do this within any of the current XGBoost implementations? Thank you.

How big is your dataset?

It isn't really about a single dataset. I am trying to build a package that potentially scales up to millions of observations with hundreds of variables and hundreds of time points. Think analyzing electronic health records. That is why I want to be efficient about data storage. I might need to eventually build something custom but thought I'd check here first in case anyone knew.

I assume you are running on a GPU?
